# Showing that interval $(a,b)$ is open in $(\mathbb{R},\tau)$

Tags: general-topology

> Let $\mathcal{B}=\left\lbrace (a,b]: a,b\in\mathbb{R}, \quad a < b\right\rbrace$. $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for a topology $\tau$ on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\tau$ is not the Euclidean Topology. Show that each interval $(a,b)$ is open in $(\mathbb{R},\tau)$.

I used proposition that says:

"Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a basis for a topology $\tau$ on a set $X$ then a subset $U$ of $X$ is open iff for each $x\in U, \exists B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B \subseteq U$".

As we see the proposition fit perfectly to our case. So I did those below:

Let $x \in (a,b)$ and $B = (c,b]$ with $c<b$ and $c<a<b$ and therefore since $x\in(a,b)$ we can say $x\in(c,b]$ and so $x\in(c,b] \subseteq (a,b)$. Thus, U is open. $\blacksquare$

Is my proof true? Thanks in advance!

Comment: $(c,b]\subseteq (a,b)$? How is that possible?

Comment: You should rather take $c,d$ s.t. $a<c<x<d<b$, and thus, indeed $x\in (c,d]\subset (a,b)$.

Comment: @Surb that's true thanks a lot! Calvin Khor thank you Surb said how should I choose!

Comment: Let me give you a hint: all unions of Open Sets are Open. Can you write (a,b) AS a union of basic open sets?

Comment: suppose $b_n\nearrow b$ and $b_n<b$ for all $n$, then  $\bigcup_n(a,b_n]=(a, b)$

Answer (score 2):

You can use the property that $\mathbb{R}$ is everywhere dense, hence for each interval $(a,b)$ and each $x\in (a,b)$ there exist $c,d\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $a<c<x\leq d<b$, thus $x\in (a,d]\subseteq (a,b)$.

An alternative proof is considering the collection of sets $ \left( a,b-\frac{1}{n} \right],n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then $$(a,b)=\bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \left( a,b-\frac{1}{n} \right].$$